# Gitlab CI: Trigger pipeline when commit contains [ci]:

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I've seen similar questions on how to implement this, but I'm running into some trouble with the pipeline never triggering whatsoever.

I want to trigger the CI pipeline only when the `[ci]:` keyword starts the commit message, relevant gitlab config:

```yaml
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ "/^\[ci\]:.+/"'
```

I've tried using this within the rules block of specific job, I've tried it within the `workflow:rules` top level declaration, and the result always ends up the pipeline/job ***NEVER*** triggers at all.

Examples:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ "/^\[ci\]:.+/"'

# another variation
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ "/^\[ci\]:.+/"'
      when: always
    - when: never

# another variation
# was not combined with the workflow ruleset, that was taken out when
# tested in just the jobs
somejob:
  stage: some-stage
  script: echo "Hello"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ "/^\[ci\]:.+/"'
```

I've tried escaping the `:` as well within the reg expr. I'm sure I'm missing something trivial here, but I've been staring at this for far too long so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for anyone that finds this later you need to do an `&&` for it to evaluate properly.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[ci\]:.+/'
```